# How to use CSV-Writer in a java script used by a website

Tags: node.js, csv, node-modules, browserify

How do I use the fs manager in a browser to edit a csv or a text file?

I tried using browserFs and it still didn't work, maybe I was doing something wrong, I'm not so sure. When I used it no errors were present but nothing was written to the file although the code specifically did so.

Comment: Please focus your question to one of CSV-writer (if your problem is perhaps just how to write CSV data to a string instead of a file with `createCsvStringifier`), BrowserFS (if you've tried something that isn't working for you -- provide the code you tried!), or access to the local filesystem from a browser (search the web first, there are lots of answers about how to do this such as the [File System Access API](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/))

Answer (score 0):

Within a browser, there is no JavaScript that can directly read and/or write to files on the file system. [BrowserFS](https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS) supports many ways to store data, but files on the file system are not one of those supported ways.